# Como programar para AVRs em C/C++? E utilizando o Arduino?

Tags: c, c++, arduino

Gostaria de saber:

1. Como iniciar a programação de microcontroladores `ATMEL AVR` em `C/C++`?
2. Que softwares posso utilizar para compilar o meu programa?
3. Que softwares posso utilizar para fazer upload do meu programa?
4. Onde encontro a referência oficial para microcontroladores `AVR`?
5. Posso utilizar um `Arduino` para programar `AVRs`?

Comment: Victor, bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Tentei ser o mais detalhista para responder a sua pergunta, no entanto, posso ter deixado passar alguma dúvida. O assunto é bastante extenso, poderia escrever um livro a respeito. Se tiver mais alguma dúvida (qualquer uma) peço que edite sua pergunta e use o campo dos comentários, que tentarei acrescentar alguma coisa e melhorar minha resposta. Cumprimentos!

Comment: Estou fechando a pergunta porque ela é ampla demais, como disse o @Avelino ela daria um livro. A resposta dele é muito boa e completa, acho muito difícil que apareça outra nesse nível. Nas próximas vezes, procure postar perguntas separadas. Vale uma olhada no nosso [tour] e na [help]. Obrigado!

Comment: Victor, talvez se você pegar sua ultima pergunta "Posso utilizar um Arduino para programar AVRs?" e recria-la da seguinte forma: "Posso utilizar um Arduino para programar AVRs com C?" Sem dúvida que você será respondido de forma simples e objetivo, solucionando todas as demais dúvidas. Caso já tenha feito comente aqui com o link por favor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## **1. Como iniciar a programação de microcontroladores ATMEL AVR em C/C++?**

Você vai precisar de:

> - Um microcontrolador (o qual se pretende gravar);
> - Um circuito gravador;
> - Um conjunto de softwares para compilar e fazer upload do código;
> - <strike>1kg de trigo;</strike>
> - <strike>8 ovos.</strike>

Existem muitos circuitos gravadores disponíveis no mercado. Além de algumas alternativas oficiais, existe o [USBtinyISP](http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/) e o [USBasp](http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/) que são bastante conhecidos. É importante dizer que os gravadores utilizam as portas SPI do microcontrolador para gravarem o firmware.

É possível começar utilizando um Arduino como gravador e microcontrolador. O Arduino possui um bootloader, o que facilita na hora de gravar, visto que a gravação é feita através do canal UART. Também é possível utilizar a própria IDE do Arduino. Os passos serão descritos mais adiante.

## **2. Que softwares posso utilizar para compilar o meu programa?**

A própria `ATMEL` fornece o [Atmel Studio](http://www.atmel.com/pt/br/Microsite/atmel_studio6/), uma IDE completa baseada no Visual Studio e que permite programar `AVRs`. Mas é possível programar usando o editor que você preferir e mais tarde compilar usando o avr-gcc (compilador) através da linha de comando. Se você for usuário Windows, baixe o [WinAVR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winavr/) e posteriormente o [`Atmel Studio`](http://www.atmel.com/pt/br/Microsite/atmel_studio6/), se você for usuário Linux é necessário baixar alguns pacotes, você pode baixar via repositório com as seguintes linhas:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install avrdude binutils-avr gcc-avr avr-libc gdb-avr
```

É possível também, utilizar o Eclipse como IDE (minha alternativa favorita) e, através de dois plugins, compilar e fazer upload a placa. Para utilizar o Eclipse, consulte [minha resposta nesta pergunta](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9538/using-an-arduino-board-to-program-an-avr/9540#9540) feita no [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9538/using-an-arduino-board-to-program-an-avr/9540#9540), da StackExchange. Lembre-se que você deve utilizar a versão para `C/C++` para que funcione. Minha resposta mostra como utilizar um Arduino como gravador, mas você pode utilizar o gravador e o microcontrolador da sua preferência.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma das coisas que gosto no eclipse é a sua interface, o recurso de autocompletar, a organização dos projetos e o recurso de mostrar quanto o seu programa vai ocupar no Program (Memória Flash) e Data (Memória RAM):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você também pode compilar usando a linha de comando, é preciso informar o clock, o modelo do microcontrolador e o nome do `arquivo.c`. Dica: utilize a flag `-Os` para que o compilador otimize o código.

```
avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p -c -o led.o led.c
avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p led.o -o led
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom led led.hex
```

O processo de compilação acima inclui a linkagem e a geração do `.hex`

## **3. Que softwares posso utilizar para fazer upload do meu programa?**

Eu conheço apenas um, o avrdude. Já vem incluso no pacote WinAVR e nos apts que citei anteriormente. Para usá-lo via linha de comando, é fácil:

```
/*avrdude -p (nome do microcontrolador) -c (nome do gravador) 
-P (nome da porta serial) -U (memória que pretende gravar):w 
(W = escrita) (nome do arquivo hexadecimal):a*/
//exemplo 1 (Linux):
avrdude -pm328p -carduino -P/dev/ttyACM0 -Uflash:w:piscaLed.hex:a 
//exemplo 2 (Linux):
avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA328P -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 -U flash:w:led.hex
//exemplo 3 (Windows):
avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA328P -P com1 -b 115200 -U flash:w:led.hex
```

Se tudo der certo, você obterá resultados semelhante a estes no seu terminal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O exemplo acima funciona utilizando um Arduino como gravador e se você estiver na mesma pasta do `.hex` (você pode informar o caminho completo na sua linha de comando). Note que é possível omitir o nome completo do microcontrolador (atmega328p) e escrever apenas `m328p`. Para mais detalhes sobre como utilizar o avrdude com a linha de comando, consulte a documentação [aqui](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude.html).

Aconselho usar uma IDE como o Atmel Studio ou Eclipse para não precisar digitar todas as vezes que quiser compilar ou fazer upload a placa. Veja a minha resposta no [Arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9538/using-an-arduino-board-to-program-an-avr/9540#9540) para informações de como utilizar o Eclipse IDE.

## **4. Onde encontro a referência oficial para microcontroladores AVR?**

As melhores referências sempre são os sites oficiais. Você pode consultar o datasheet do microcontrolador que você utilizará, no site da Atmel (exemplo para o [microcontrolador atmega328p](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf)), a referência para o avr-libc [aqui](http://nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/), [aqui](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/), [aqui](http://www2.cs.uidaho.edu/~rinker/cs404/avr-libc-user-manual-1.6.1.pdf) e [aqui](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/UsingAVR) e a do avrdude [aqui](http://www.nongnu.org/avrdude/user-manual/avrdude.html). Mas, felizmente, existem bons materiais escritos em português. Inclusive, pelas minhas pesquisas, os materiais em português são bem mais didáticos que os em inglês. Recomendo [esta apostila](http://files.arduinoprojects.webnode.pt/200000013-ed611ee5ba/Apostila-ATMEGA.pdf) distribuída livremente na Internet e o livro `AVR e Arduino: Técnicas de Projeto` de Charles Lima e Marco Vilaça (Não é propaganda, o livro é ótimo). Também recomendo [esta referência](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/avr/index.html).

## **5. Posso utilizar um Arduino para programar AVRs?**

Sim, absolutamente!

## **AVR X Arduino**

O Arduino utiliza de microcontroladores `AVR` em sua plataforma. A IDE do Arduino é feita em Java e utiliza o avrdude e o avr-gcc por debaixo dos panos (veja só!), desta forma, é possível usar a própria IDE do Arduino para compilar seus programas escritos em `C/C++`. O Arduino faz uma tradução de códigos escritos em Wiring para `C/C++` adicionando bastante lixo. O código que estamos acostumados a ver na IDE, é convertido para algo semelhante a:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL    
#include <avr/io.h>        
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup(){
}

void loop(){
}

int main(){
    setup();
    while(1){
       loop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Mas isto é somente uma parte do código gerado. O Arduino ainda converte o nome dos "pinos oficiais" e adiciona as suas próprias funções para manipulação do hardware e `IO`. Uma das enormes vantagens de se trabalhar diretamente com `AVRs`, sem fazer uso da IDE do Arduino e programando diretamente em `C/C++`, é a otimização que isto traz, além da liberdade de poder manipular o hardware diretamente.

A imagem a seguir mostra o nome dos pinos oficiais de um atmega328p em relação com os pinos de um Arduino Uno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## **AVR X Arduino - O teste final, que fará você escolher programar em AVRs**

Observe o seguinte código para Arduino:

```
/*
  Blink
  Turns on an LED on for one second, then off for one second, repeatedly.

  This example code is in the public domain.
 */

// Pin 13 has an LED connected on most Arduino boards.
// give it a name:
int led = 13;

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {                
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage     level)
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
}
```

O código é um exemplo oficial, disponível nas IDEs Arduino e no site. Ele simplesmente faz o LED conectado a porta 13 (PB5) piscar com intervalos de um segundo. Ao compilar o código acima, podemos verificar que ele ocupa **1.056 bytes** na memória flash.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora observe o código abaixo:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL    
#include <avr/io.h>        
#include <util/delay.h> 

int main(){
    DDRB = 0xFF;  //configura todos os pinos do PORTB como saídas
    while(1){
        PORTB = 0b00010000;    //Coloca o pino PB5 em nível alto
        _delay_ms(1000);       //Delay de 1 segundo
        PORTB = 0b00000000;    //Coloca todos os pinos em nível baixo
       _delay_ms(1000);        //Delay de 1 segundo
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Cole-o na IDE do Arduino se você não tiver instalado o Atmel Studio ou Eclipse e pressione o botão de compilar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é possível observar, o código ocupa apenas **180 bytes!**. Isto é apenas um exemplo besta, com um programa de piscar um LED, mas que comprova que é possível escrever um código otimizado utilizando `C/C++`. Ainda é possível otimizá-lo mais ainda, usando macros. Vamos ao exemplo:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL    
#include <avr/io.h>        
#include <util/delay.h> 


#define set_bit(Y,bit_x) (Y|=(1<<bit_x))    //ativa o bit x da variável Y (coloca em 1)
#define clr_bit(Y,bit_x) (Y&=~(1<<bit_x))   //limpa o bit x da variável Y (coloca em 0) 
#define tst_bit(Y,bit_x) (Y&(1<<bit_x))     //testa o bit x da variável Y (retorna 0 ou 1)
#define cpl_bit(Y,bit_x) (Y^=(1<<bit_x))    //troca o estado do bit x da variável Y (complementa)

#define LED PB5     //PB5 é o mesmo pino 13 do Arduino, que contém um LED.          

int main(){
    DDRB = 0xFF;  //configura todos os pinos do PORTB como saídas
    while(1){
        set_bit(PORTB,LED);    //Coloca o pino PB5 em nível alto
        _delay_ms(1000);       //Delay de 1 segundo
        clr_bit(PORTB,LED);    //Coloca todos os pinos em nível baixo
       _delay_ms(1000);        //Delay de 1 segundo
    }
    return 0;
}
```

O código acima ocupa **178 bytes**. As macros `set_bit` e `clr_bit` funcionam de forma semelhante ao `digitalWrite` do Arduino. Se não souber como elas funcionam, pode fazer uma outra pergunta que eu tento responder. Mas se você for realmente fanático por otimização, pode simplesmente colocar:

```
cpl_bit(PORTB,LED);    //Troca o estado do pino PB5
_delay_ms(1000);       //Delay de 1 segundo
```

dentro do while e o código passará a ocupar **164 bytes!!!**. Bem menos que os **1.056 bytes** que o Arduino gera para piscar o mesmo LED não é mesmo?

Bem, poderia escrever um livro a respeito. Tentei abordar alguns pontos principais, com intuito de "dar um norte". Caso tenha mais alguma dúvida, edite a sua pergunta ou poste nos comentários.

Comment: Agora você já pode sair piscando LEDs por aí.

Comment: Muito completa a resposta. Enviarei um pacote de trigo e ovos de agradecimento.

Comment: Excelente resposta @Avelino, completa e ainda compara as duas maneiras de programar. Mostra que não há mágica nas coisas. Mas certamente, caso não fosse essa maneira mais simples e direta de programar do Arduino, ele não teria feito tanto sucesso pelo mundo. O que eu acho mais importante na sua resposta é que as pessoas saibam que dá pra otimizar, caso seja necessário. Eu sou um fã do Arduino exatamente porque ele conseguiu simplificar algo que é em sua essência é complexo.

Comment: Eu gosto da ideia do Arduino. Mas não recomendaria utilizá-lo em aplicações comerciais complexas. O Arduino, bem como sua biblioteca, está a pouco tempo no mercado e não foi devidamente testado para ser considerado seguro em aplicações industriais. Digo isto pois já encontrei bugs nas bibliotecas. Mas a ideia e a simplicidade do Arduino fazem ele ser o que é. Eu comecei a aprender eletrônica com Arduino. Uso para fazer protótipos e aplicações rápidas, para aprender a lidar com um componente e para aprender sobre programação e eletrônica.